# How to override the Library Variable value from the yaml in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the Variable Group defined in the Library:

[image]

I'm trying to override the value of the variable defined in above library in the specific task of Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline:

```yaml
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
 - group: DevGroup

steps:
- script: |
   echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VanisJob;isoutput=true]FSDeveloper"
   echo $(VanisJob)

- script: |
   echo $(VanisJob) is the 2nd Job
```

**Result**:

**1st Script result**

[image]

***2nd script result - here value should be changed as defined in the YAML Pipeline but not changed***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your yaml sample, you are using logging command to set the variable name: **HarisJob**.

The variable name is different from the variable name in the Variable group.

In this case, it will create a new variable(name: HarisJob) instead of overriding the variable value in the Variable Group.

To solve this issue, you need to set the same variable name in the Pipeline and the variable group when using logging command to set the variable.

For example:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
 - group: DevGroup

steps:
- script: |
   echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VanisJob]FSDeveloper"
   echo "$(VanisJob)"

- script: |
   echo "$(VanisJob) is the 2nd Job"
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Note:**  You need to remove the **isoutput=true** in the logging command, otherwise the variable name will change to **$(CMDLINE1.VANISJOB)**

For example:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VanisJob]FSDeveloper"
```

Comment: Sorry, the variable name is mistaken in the question. I corrected. and the solution given I'm checking now.

Comment: No problem. In this case, you need to remove the  **isoutput=true** in the logging command.  Then it will work. If you set the isoutput=true, the variable name will change to $(CMDLINE1.VANISJOB). Then the pipeline will have two variables: one is $(CMDLINE1.VANISJOB), the other is $(VANISJOB)

Comment: Yes, got it. But what does this flag `isoutput=true`?

Comment: If you need to use the variable cross the stages or jobs, this should be required. If the variable is using the tasks of the same job, this is not required. When you use the isoutput flag, it will add the task name as prefix

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable we can refer to this doc.